# Trying to use a bash script with mysqldump not working

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, mysql

First of all thanks in advance, I am trying to use a Bash script to automate the backup of databases, when i run the `mysqldump` script on the terminal it works:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p123 testt1 > home/zmq/Desktop/mysqlbackup/secondtestts.sql
```

but when i try to run it from the bash script i get a message saying `file not found`, does anyone know what could be the problem?

```
#!/bin/bash
EXPECTED_ARGS=1
which mysqldump
#$1 = dbname
# Dump database into SQL file
mysqldump -uroot -p123 $1 > home/zmq/Desktop/mysqlbackup/$1.sql
```

Comment: Have you tried `set -x`? And it seems you're not showing us all the code since the first two lines are useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change :

```
home/zmq/Desktop/mysqlbackup/$1.sql
```

with :

```
"/home/zmq/Desktop/mysqlbackup/$1.sql"
```

I guess your script is not at the root of your file system, but maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: i just did thanks, by the way, do you have any experience with running this same kind of scripts on docker containers?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know docker. Good luck.